# Google enabled Chat on iPhone

Tags: chat, google

**Does Google have an iPhone app that supports Googel Talk \ Gmail chat?**

Google says:

> No need to download or install anything. Start chatting from your
>   iPhone's browser at: http://www.google.com/talk

However for me that link doesn't give chat, but redirects to a help page...

Comment: We have a guide on [ask] that might assist you in explaining in more detail what you don't get. For me, that page has a "technical requirements" link as option 2 that clearly says you need a computer OS and not iOS to use talk. What makes you think that link is meant to work on iPhones with iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question was asked, Google released their [Google Hangouts](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/hangouts/id643496868) app which does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

- There is a google Talk application (unofficial) : 
  https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/chat-for-google-talk-pro-push/id426339333?mt=8
- Or here at Mashable they wrote an article about a couple apps that let you use google talk on the iPhone :
  http://mashable.com/2012/08/27/google-talk-iphone-apps/

Comment: FYI (for future readers): The Google talk application shared is not an official one from Google.